# How to make a queue for spotify sdk android

Tags: java, android, spotify

I have an arraylist of songs uri from spotify using android sdk. But only one song is playing I want to detect when one song is complete so that I can initiate another song below is the code I am using.

```
Config playerConfig = new Config(this,sharedPreferences.getString(KEY,""),CLIENT_ID);
Spotify.getPlayer(playerConfig, this, new SpotifyPlayer.InitializationObserver() {
    @Override
    public void onInitialized(SpotifyPlayer spotifyPlayer) {
        mPlayer = spotifyPlayer;
        // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,mPlayer.getMetadata().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // System.out.println(response.getAccessToken());

        mPlayer.addNotificationCallback(PlaySong.this);

        mPlayer.play(track.get(curr).getUriFull(), 0, 0);
        mPlayer.queue(track.get(1).getUriFull());
        // mPlayer.addPlayerNotificationCallback(MainActivity.this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable throwable) {

    }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I solved the problem myself after spending sometime on it. Below is the solution if anyone ever needs it.

```
 mPlayer.addNotificationCallback(new Player.NotificationCallback() {

                            @Override
                            public void onPlaybackEvent(PlayerEvent playerEvent) {

                                if(playerEvent==PlayerEvent.kSpPlaybackNotifyTrackDelivered){


                                Toast.makeText(PlaySong.this,"Delivered",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                System.out.println("Delivered");



                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onPlaybackError(Error error) {

                            }
                        });
```

Just Simply check this condition `if(playerEvent==PlayerEvent.kSpPlaybackNotifyTrackDelivered)`